# Laravel many through relation filter using single where condition

Tags: php, laravel

I have set of users, customers and they are related, and it will change every month, my requirement is get active month user for customers.

My Customer Model

```
public function executives()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_customer_mapping', 'user_customer_mapping_customer_id', 'user_customer_mapping_user_id');
    }
```

**user_customer_mapping** table have a Column for month with values like (Y-m), i need to find "2020-10" executive for all customers

```
$month= '2020-10';
$Executive = $customer->executives()->where('user_farmer_mapping_season', $month)->first();
return ($fieldExecutive) ? $fieldExecutive->name : 'N/A';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by adding [withPivot](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#retrieving-intermediate-table-columns) to your relationship so the additional pivot table columns are loaded also:

```
public function executives()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_customer_mapping', 'user_customer_mapping_customer_id', 'user_customer_mapping_user_id')
                ->withPivot('month');
}
```

Next, use [wherePivot](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#filtering-relationships-via-intermediate-table-columns) to query against the pivot table column(s):

```
$month= '2020-10';
$Executive = $customer->executives()->wherePivot('month', $month)->first();
return ($fieldExecutive) ? $fieldExecutive->name : 'N/A';
```